# How can I check wishlist data is empty or not in firebase database

Tags: java, android

I want to check "Wishlist" under User UID is empty or not because if "Wishlist" is empty I am going to create the "Wishlist 2" in it. How can I check this "Wishlist is empty or not in my firebase database.

The concept is like this - check wishlist  is empty or not, if wishlist is empty then I will create another wishlist 2 in database.                                                                                  Wishlist is not default it will only create if user add e.g. item 1 in wishlist                           and then if user already add item 1 in wishlist. I will create wishlist 2 for his item 2

[image: Here is my screen shot of the firebase database1]

Here is my code

```
public class web_view extends AppCompatActivity {
    //for fav
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_v);

        //fab start here
        
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String passURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
                if (passURL.matches("[0-9]+") && passURL.length()>= 10){ ////if fav book input is ISBN number
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Wishlist")// which child goes to under the current user UID
                            .setValue("http://www.librarything.com/isbn/" + passURL).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(web_view.this, "Saved to Wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else {//if wish list book is no ISBN
                    Toast.makeText(web_view.this, "Can't Save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: When you create that object in your firebase database, does it have a Wishlist field by default? What is the value of that field? So, when you create your user inside the database, and he doesn't have a wishlist, do you create that field and value do you pass to it? If it doesn't have you should place value: null. Then when you get that value back, check if it's null and do what you need to do.

Comment: The concept is like this - check wishlist  is empty or not, if wishlist is empty then i will create another wishlist 2 in database.                                                                                  Wishlist is not default it will only create if user add e.g. item 1 in wishlist                           and then if user already add item 1 in wishlist i will create wishlist 2 for his item 2 @SlothCoding

Comment: You keep saying "if the wishlist is empty then I will create another one", but do you mean if it's not empty? Because in your case Wishlist will never be empty since it's a user-created field and it always has a value?

Comment: if wishlist is not empty, item one will go to wishlist one. It is not user-created field it will only create when user add some item since it is not user information.

Comment: I don't really get you, but here is another approach. Why don't you create a List<String> of Wishlist items? So each time user adds a new item you just retrieve the list from firebase, add a new value, and save a new list to the same field? Or you'll be able to do it without retrieving, just reference to that List inside the database and pass your value with autogenerated ID or something.

Comment: I tried to do list<String> but I don't know how to do. This is why I plan to keep adding items in different filed like "wishlist", "wishlist 2". If u can help me to add items in same field "wishlist " I would really appreciate.

Comment: I'll post you an answer

Comment: Thanks sir I really apricate your help

Comment: Got it. I really apricate your help thanks <3 @SlothCoding

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding!

Comment: @SlothCoding would you mind telling me how to retrieve these stored Wishlist

Comment: There is in my answer on how you can do that. Just create a database reference to Wishlist and use the listener to get the value. The snapshot will have all Wishlist items inside, so just use foreach to loop and use data like this: for (DataSnapshot wishlist_item : snapshot) then do something with wishlist_item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you can do it with `.push()` which will autogenerate ID for each of your elements inside the Wishlist. So you can do it like this:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstace().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Wishlist");
myRef.push().setValue(newWishlistString);
```

This will generate something like this in Firebase:

[image]

Then you can just retrieve it like this:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstace().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Wishlist");

myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               //do something here with data
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```